# Why does the variance of =2Θ+3 , where Θ and  are standard normal random variables, is equal to 9?

Tags: random-variables, normal-distribution, variance

I dont understand why the variance is equal to 9 and actually why the mean is $2\cdot \theta$.

Comment: That is not true.

Comment: I think you mean to say $\Theta$ is a non-random constant and $W$ is standard normal.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It isn't.
$$
\mathbb{E}(2\Theta+3W) = 2\mathbb{E}(\Theta)+3\mathbb{E}(W)=2\cdot 0 +3\cdot 0=0.$$
If $\Theta$ and $W$ are independent,
$$\mathbb{V}(2\Theta+3W) = 2^2\mathbb{V}(\Theta)+3^2\mathbb{V}(W)=4\cdot 1 +9\cdot 1=13.$$

---

If instead $\Theta$ is constant and $W$ is standard normal,
$$
\mathbb{E}(2\Theta+3W) = 2\mathbb{E}(\Theta)+3\mathbb{E}(W)=2\Theta +3\cdot 0=2\Theta$$
and
$$\mathbb{V}(2\Theta+3W) = 2^2\mathbb{V}(\Theta)+3^2\mathbb{V}(W)=4\cdot 0 +9\cdot 1=9.$$

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you meant for $\theta$ to be constant (I've decapitalised it because statisticians reserve upper case for non-constant random variables),$$\operatorname{Var}(2\theta+3W)=\operatorname{Var}(3W)=3^2\operatorname{Var}W=9\times1=9.$$